# Compare with a local sequence in Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I got a local `List<DateInterval>` where `DateInterval` is:

```
internal class DateInterval{
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get all the events on the database that matches at least one of the `DateInterval`.

Ideally I'll do something like:

```
var query = from _event in db.GetTable<Event>()
            where dates.Any(d => d.StartDate <= _event.Date && d.EndDate > _event.Date)
            select _event;
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except     the Contains() operator
```

Since the `.Contain()` method only accept exact results instead of timestamps, is there a way to achieve the desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic option here is to materialize the query from the database and then perform the comparison against the list in memory.

```
var query = yourSqlQuery.AsEnumerable() // forces* evaluation
                        .Where(...) // happens in memory
```

Obviously, the more filtering you can perform at the DB in order to pull less results into memory, the better, but in this case, your options are limited.

```
var query = db.GetTable<Event>().AsEnumerable().Where(event => dates.Any(...));
```

---

*The evaluation is still deferred until you *use* the results of the query, but the filtering from the additional `Where` will happen in memory, the portion before `AsEnumerable()` will occur at the database.

Comment: I was trying to reduce the result set from the DB. The best I could do was to only get the events between the minimum startDate and max endDate of the List<DateInterval> and do the adicional filtering in memory